# Date Format in Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timestamp

I'm moving data from the old project to my laravel project the start date format was in this format 1496242424 ,1496269010 How I convert it to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code to calculate days
firt of all $request->Fdate is for starting date
$request->Tdate is for end date,

```
$fdate=$request->Fdate;
$tdate=$request->Tdate;

$start = Carbon::parse($fdate)->format('Y/m/d');
$end =  Carbon::parse($tdate)->format('Y/m/d');
$days = $end->diffInDays($start);

echo $days;

exit;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, other than just the code.

Answer (score 1):

To a Carbon object which can be saved on your models, if you add the field to the `$dates` property.

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1496242424);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert like this

```
<?php 
echo $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1496242424); 
?>
```

output :

```
2017-05-31 16:53:44
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple use `date` function in php To convert this to time use below code

```
echo date('Y-m-d',1496242424);
```

output of above code will be

```
2017-05-31
```

and to convert this to datetime use below code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1496242424);
```

output of above code will be

```
2017-05-31 02:53:44
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why convert it to dateTime. keep it as unix timestamp. Just add a method in your model to tell it to use unix timestamp

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your datepicker and the format is changed as per your own choice

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
```

Set this line in your controller

```
$post->start_date =Carbon::parse(strtotime($request->start_date))->format('Y-m-d');
```

You should use carbon library `use Carbon/Carbon;`